# Android SQLite Search using Like is not Case Insensitive on UTF-8 characters

Tags: android, sqlite, utf-8, case-insensitive

I want to get all entries that contain a needle in their display name.
The length and content of the needle are not defined (dynamic).

The best I could come up with was to use the LIKE operator:
`DISPLAY_NAME LIKE needle`

Which works brilliantly for case sensitive searches.
This one should be a case insensitive search though.
I also tried `DISPLAY_NAME LIKE needle COLLATE NOCASE`
which works perfectly for ASCII characters, but not for UNICODE

I also tried:
`DISPLAY_NAME LIKE needle COLLATE UNICODE`
`DISPLAY_NAME LIKE needle COLLATE LOCALIZED`
but none of them works.

Finally, I tried `LOWER( DISPLAY_NAME ) LIKE LOWER( needle )`
as above, but also combined with the collations and none seems to work.

My test phone is running 2.3.7, but I am looking for a generic solution. Ideas?

Comment: Have you considered a full text search?

Comment: @PeterBirdsall, thanks! No, because I am trying to query the contact providers. Is FTS supported there, or I would have to create my own custom table?